# Error : WELD-001408 Unsatisfied dependencies

Tags: java, web-applications, wildfly

I tried to follow this tutorial

> https://jaxenter.de/jax-rs-20-websocket-13453 (German tutorial)

Now I'm stuck. I've done all things till Listening 4. Now I wanted to try if it works which I did.
The most of the code is just duplicated with some other variable names but when I try to deploy this program on my server it always shows me:

> Caused by: org.jboss.weld.exceptions.DeploymentException: WELD-001408: Unsatisfied dependencies for type MarketPriceStore with qualifiers @Default
>     at injection point [UnbackedAnnotatedField] @Inject private ws.SimpleStockMarketResource.marketPriceStore
>     at ws.SimpleStockMarketResource.marketPriceStore(SimpleStockMarketResource.java:0)

So something's wrong with Class MarketPriceStore and I don't know what...

My code of MarketPriceStore

```
@Singleton
@LocalBean

public class MarketPriceStore {
    private Map<String,Double> map = new HashMap<String,Double>();

@Inject
Event<MarketpriceChangedEventObject> eventSource;

public void store(String companyName, Double marktPreisNeu){
    Double marktPreisAlt = map.get(companyName);

    if(!Objects.equals(marktPreisAlt, marktPreisNeu)){
        map.put(companyName,marktPreisNeu);
        eventSource.fire(new MarketpriceChangedEventObject(companyName, marktPreisNeu));
    }
}

public Optional<Double> retrieve(String key){
    return Optional.ofNullable(map.get(key));
}
```

I've already asked a colleague and we googled a bit but none of the answers were satisfying.

My code for MarketpriceChangedEventObject

```
public class MarketpriceChangedEventObject {
public final String companyName;
public final Double marktpreis;
public MarketpriceChangedEventObject(String companyName, Double marktpreis){
    this.companyName = companyName;
    this.marktpreis = marktpreis;
    }
}
```

My code for SimpleStockMarketResource

```
    public class SimpleStockMarketResourceClient {

    private static final String URI = "http://localhost:8080/Entenhausen/ws/SimpleStockMarketResource";

    public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {
        try {
            String operation = args[0];
            String companyName = args[1];

            if (operation.equalsIgnoreCase("-get")) {
                Double marketPrice = ClientBuilder.newClient()
                        .target(URI)
                        .path("{companyName}")
                        .resolveTemplate("companyName", companyName)
                        .request()
                        .get(Double.class);
                System.out.println("SUCCESS: Get! => [Market Price=" + marketPrice + "]");
            } else if (operation.equalsIgnoreCase("-set")) {
                Double marketPrice = Double.valueOf(args[2]);

                Response response = ClientBuilder.newClient()
                        .target(URI)
                        .path("{companyName}")
                        .resolveTemplate("companyName", companyName)
                        .request()
                        .put(Entity.text(marketPrice));

                if (response.getStatusInfo().getFamily() == Response.Status.Family.SUCCESSFUL) {
                    System.out.println("SUCCESS: Set!");
                } else {
                    System.err.println("ERROR: Set! => [Status Code=" + response.getStatus() + "]");
                }
            }
        } catch (Exception e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: I'm not sure the error is in this class. can you post your source for MarketpriceChangedEventObject and SimpleStockMarketResource?

Comment: I'll edit it in a few moments

Comment: you posted the code for your client rather than SimpleStockMarketResource. I think the error might be there.

Comment: ah yeah lol you are rigth bit confused sometimes ...
But thanks first :D I simple didn't injected a variabla in SimpleStockMarketResource and it worked xD